# Bootstrap "multiple" attribute for simple_form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I would like to have a scroll down menu with different options to choose from using Bootstrap, as demonstrated [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls):

```
  <select multiple class="form-control">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
```

I am currently using simple_form to construct my menu (it is a dropdown menu by default):

```
<%= f.input :member_type, collection: Form::MEMBERSHIPS, include_blank: true, error: false %>
```

Which outputs as such:

```
<div class="form-group select required form_member_type"><label class="select required control-label" for="form_member_type"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Member type</label><select class="select required form-control" name="form[member_type]" id="form_member_type"><option value=""></option>
<option value="Monthly member: $55">Monthly member: $55</option>
<option value="Pay-Per-Use (cash): 15% discount">Pay-Per-Use (cash): 15% discount</option>
<option value="Youth member: $35">Youth member: $35</option>
<option value="Monthly with children (Friday&#39;s): $55 + $16 per child">Monthly with children (Friday&#39;s): $55 + $16 per child</option>
<option value="Other - specify in notes">Other - specify in notes</option></select></div>
```

I need to somehow insert the `multiple` attribute into the select tag. Is there a technique to do this using embedded Ruby without having to manually edit the html code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace your code with following line

```
<%= f.input :member_type, collection: Form::MEMBERSHIPS, include_blank: true, error: false,:input_html => {:multiple => true} %>
```

Hope I answered your question.